# IF and Else Statement Exception Handling Help - Else message does not work

Tags: c#, if-statement, exception

The else statement does not work, when the input into the console is not Rock, Paper or Scissors the exception message does not show. What is the reason for this.

```
using System;

namespace Rock__Paper__Scissors_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lets play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
            Console.Write("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors:");
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            Random r = new Random();
            int computerChoice = r.Next(3);

            //0 = Scissors
            if (computerChoice == 0)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");

                }
            }

            //1 = Rock
            else if (computerChoice == 1)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }
            }

            //2 = Paper
            else if (computerChoice == 2)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }
            }

            //3 = Exception Handling
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You must enter Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            }


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Try stepping through the code with the debugger. The "else" you're referring to, the one that should say "`You must enter Rock, Paper or Scissors`" is only shown when the `computerChoice` is not one of `0`, `1`, `2`. It's not dependent on user input (`Rock`, `Paper`, `Scissors`).

Comment: You have the ‘else’ on the computer’s choices

Comment: Ahh ok, thats makes sence. I will try something different. Thanks.

Comment: yeah... `else` is never going to hit because `computerChoice` is always going to be between 0 and 2

Comment: You should really expand on the "else statement does not work" comment

Answer (score 0):

Check the value or `userChoice` before proceeding... My preference would be to use a `while` loop

```
using System;

namespace Rock__Paper__Scissors_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lets play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
            Console.Write("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors:");
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            //Check it here in a while loop, until the user gets it 
            //right, the program will not proceed and loop here
            while (userChoice != "Scissors" || userChoice != "Rock" || userChoice != "Paper")
            {
                Console.Write("You must enter Rock, Paper or Scissors");
                userChoice = Console.ReadLine();
            }

            Random r = new Random();
            int computerChoice = r.Next(3);

            //0 = Scissors
            if (computerChoice == 0)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");

                }
            }

            //1 = Rock
            else if (computerChoice == 1)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }
            }

            //2 = Paper
            else if (computerChoice == 2)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Added some more if/if else statements instead of an else. It now spits the exception error I wanted.

Purpose of making this was to practice/apply if, if else and else methods as I am trying to learn c# and working through some tutorials online. Granted there are probably better ways to make this game.

-Need to add some kind of loop (when I learn how to do them).
-The computer seems to generate the random number in a predictable sequence and doesnt seem quite so random so I need to work on improving this.

using System;

```
namespace Rock__Paper__Scissors_
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Lets play a game of Rock, Paper, Scissors.");
            Console.Write("Enter Rock, Paper or Scissors:");
            string userChoice = Console.ReadLine();

            Random r = new Random();
            int computerChoice = r.Next(2);


            //0 = Scissors
            if (computerChoice == 0)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Scissors");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");

                }
            }

            //1 = Rock
            else if (computerChoice == 1)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock!");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Rock");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN!");
                }
            }

            //2 = Paper
            else if (computerChoice == 2)
            {
                if (userChoice == "Scissors")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You WIN");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Rock")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper!");
                    Console.WriteLine("You LOSE!");
                }

                else if (userChoice == "Paper")
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Computer chose Paper");
                    Console.WriteLine("TIE!");
                }
            }


            //Exception Handling
            if (userChoice != "Scissors")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            }

            else if (userChoice != "Rock")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            }

            else if (userChoice != "Paper")
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Choose Rock, Paper or Scissors");
            }


        }
    }
}
```